# SQL Select Query - "Pairing" Records Together

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's my data:

Table1...

```
id 
field1
field2
...
```

Table2...

```
id
table1_original_id
table1_new_id
```

Table1 holds records that cannot themselves be updated though I built a mechanism for my users to be able to "update" them... they select a record, make changes, and those changes are actually submitted as a new record.  For conversation's sake let's assume there are currently 10 records in Table1 with IDs 1 through 10.  User submits an update to ID 3.  ID 3 remains as it was and a new record, ID 11, is added to Table1.  Along with this new record, Table2 gets a new record, with ID = 1,  t1_original_id = 3 and t1_new_id = 11.

What would be by SQL select to retrieve the "pairs" of records from Table1... in this case the query would provide me with... IDs 3 and 11.

*scratching head*

I don't think it matters much by DB platform is Postgres 8.4 and I'm retrieving the data via PHP to be processed in jqGrid.  Bonus points if you can point me in the direction of displaying each pair of records in a separate jqGrid!

Thanks for your time and effort.

=== EDIT ===
The following is a sample of what I need returned from the query based on the scenario above:

```
id    field1    field2
3     blah      stuff
11    more      things
```

Once I have these pairs back I can process them further, as necessary, on the PHP side.

Comment: Why are you using 2 tables for this?. But, more important, what is it exactly that you want?, can you post a desired result?

Comment: The application has an "approval" system - the way it was designed is that the original record stays in tact until the new record is approved (or rejected)... when approved the original is deleted.  What I need to be returned is the entire record for both records in the pair... the user in an approver role can then see each to compare so an approve/reject decision can be made.

Comment: "What I need is the entire record for both records in the pair", sorry, I don't understand what that means, that's why I asked if you could post a desired results, since it would be easier to understand that way

Comment: Added a sample of what I need returned - the records come from Table1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Standard SQL solution

To get *two separate rows* (as later specified in the Q update) use a [**`UNION`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION) query:

```sql
SELECT 'old' AS version, t1.id, t1.field1, t1.field2
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t2.table1_original_id = t1.id
WHERE  t2.id =  $some_t2_id  -- your t2.id here!

UNION ALL
SELECT 'new' as version, t1.id, t1.field1, t1.field2
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t2.table1_new_id = t1.id
WHERE  t2.id =  $some_t2_id;  -- your t2.id here!
```

Note: this is *one* query.
Returns as requested, plus a column **`version` to distinguish the rows** reliably:

```sql
version | id | field1 | field2
--------+----+--------+--------
old     | 3  |  blah  | stuff
new     | 11 |  more  | things
```

#### Faster Postgres-specific solution

A more sophisticated, but shorter and faster solution:

```sql
SELECT version, id, field1, field2
FROM   (
   SELECT unnest(ARRAY['old', 'new']) AS version 
         ,unnest(ARRAY[table1_original_id, table1_new_id]) AS id
   FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = $some_t2_id -- your t2.id here!
   ) t2
JOIN   table1 USING (id);
```

Same result.

[-> SQLfiddle demo for both.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/3859e/8)

Comment: This query returns zero records... unless I take the WHERE clause out - I'll have to do some more testing but this will either work or get me very close.  Out of curiosity, what's the deal with the WHERE?  ... = 1?  The records in Table2 won't always be ID 1 and I don't actually need that field.  Maybe you see/know something I don't!  :)  I had a hunch UNION was a part of the solution but was failing at making it happen.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1801810: `1` would be `table2.id`. Also added a faster, Postgres-specific version

Comment: Thanks everybody for your efforts.  All of the latest proposed solutions work as requested.  Bonus points for the Postgres version.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `JOIN` to `Table1` twice, something like:

```
SELECT orig.id AS Orig_ID
     , orig.value AS Orig_Value
     , n.id AS New_ID
     , n.value AS New_Value
FROM Table2 a
JOIN Table1 AS orig
  ON a.table1_original_id = orig.id
JOIN Table1 AS n
  ON a.table1_new_id = n.id
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/fc115/3/0)

Update:
To get them paired as you want without manually choosing a set you'll need something like this:

```
SELECT sub.id,sub.value
FROM (SELECT a.id as Update_ID,o.id,o.value, '1' AS sort
      FROM Table2 a
      JOIN Table1 AS o
        ON a.table1_original_id = o.id
      UNION
      SELECT a.id as Update_ID, n.id,n.value, '2' AS sort
      FROM Table2 a
      JOIN Table1 AS n
        ON a.table1_new_id = n.id
      ) AS sub
ORDER BY Update_ID,sort
```

Demo: [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fc115/6/0)

Notes: Change `UNION` to `UNION` + `ALL`, can't post those words next to each other due to firewall limitation.
       The hard-coded '1' and '2' are so that original always appear before new.

Comment: You'll need distinct column aliases to tell columns apart.

Comment: This sample query only returns one of the two records - seems to be the first (the original record that got "updated" into a new one).

Comment: See updated answer, need the unique column aliases as @ErwinBrandstetter mentioned, and `new` is not a good alias in postgresql it turns out.

Comment: @Goat CO - thanks very much, is there any way to get this back as multiple records?  So in the sample scenario rather than a single record with the original and updated data, as you provided the query for, it comes as two records?

Comment: Not sure I follow, the result would be two rows per record in Table2? one for old, one for new?

Comment: Yes, I understand that but ideally I need two records... much easier to handle then on the PHP/jqGrid side.  You're exactly correct though, one record is the old and the other is new.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your efforts.  All of the latest proposed solutions work as requested.